# Shallow/deep copy of std::map

Tags: c++, deep-copy, stdmap, shallow-copy

How would I best implement these? I thought of something like this:

```
    using namespace std;

    shape_container
    shape_container::clone_deep () const
    {
        shape_container* ptr = new shape_container();
        copy( data.begin(), data.end(), (*ptr).begin() );
        return *ptr;
    }

    shape_container
    shape_container::clone_shallow () const
    {
        return *( new shape_container(*this) );
    }
```

The member `data` is defined as follows:

```
    std::map<std::string, shape*> data;
```

This doesn't work, unfortunately. Here's the compiler errors, I don't really understand them:

```
    g++ -Wall -O2 -pedantic -I../../UnitTest++/src/ -I./libfglwin/include/ -I. -c shape_container.cpp -o shape_container.o
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h: In member function ‘std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*>& std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*>::operator=(const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*>&)’:
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:69:   instantiated from ‘static _OI std::__copy<<anonymous>, <template-parameter-1-2> >::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >, _OI = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >, bool <anonymous> = false, <template-parameter-1-2> = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag]’
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:315:   instantiated from ‘_OI std::__copy_aux(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >, _OI = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >]’
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:340:   instantiated from ‘static _OI std::__copy_normal<<anonymous>, <anonymous> >::__copy_n(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >, _OI = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >, bool <anonymous> = false, bool <anonymous> = false]’
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:401:   instantiated from ‘_OutputIterator std::copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _OutputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >, _OutputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >]’
    shape_container.cpp:70:   instantiated from here
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:69: error: non-static const member ‘const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*>::first’, can't use default assignment operator
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h: In static member function ‘static _OI std::__copy<<anonymous>, <template-parameter-1-2> >::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >, _OI = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*> >, bool <anonymous> = false, <template-parameter-1-2> = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag]’:
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:268: note: synthesized method ‘std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*>& std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*>::operator=(const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, shape*>&)’ first required here
```

Somehow this looks unnecessarily complicated to me. Is that 
true and can I make it better?

BTW, I have clone() methods 
in the classes I derived from shape. Perhaps I can use them 
for the clone_deep method? Are they ok? They look something 
like this:

```
    class shape
    {
        public:
            /* Many methods. */
            virtual shape* clone () const = 0;

        protected:
            colorRGB    color_;
            std::string name_;
    };

    class triangle2d : public shape
    {
        public:
            /* Many methods. */
            triangle2d* clone() const;
        private:
            point3d a_, b_, c_;
    };

    triangle2d*
    triangle2d::clone() const
    {
        return new triangle2d(*this);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to shallow/deep copy the map, or the shapes the map holds?

Comment: Who or what is responsible for deleting the things stored in the maps? The whole idea of deep/shallow copies is something of an anti-pattern in C++.

Comment: The shallow copy of the shape_container should return a copied map, containing pointers to the _same_ shapes. the deep copy should return a copied map containing pointers to _copied_ shapes.

Comment: It's not so much an anti-pattern as it's simply not meaningful. Each class defines *one* way in which it can be copied. The copy constructor and assignment operator of a class define whether the members of the class are copied.

It's not like Java where `x = y` performs a shallow (reference) copy. In C++, it invokes the assignment operator, which copies the object itself. (Unless `x` and  `y` are pointers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a clone function would return a pointer to a new instance. What you are returning is an object by value which is copy constructed from a dynamically allocated isntance that is then leaked.

If you want to return by value then you should not use `new`.
E.g.

```
shape_container shape_container::clone_shallow () const
{
    return *this;
}
```

If the `data` member is just a `std::map` instance, then it will be copied as part of your shallow clone in any case so there is no need to do the `std::copy` in the deep clone case, it's not trying to do anything different.

If you wanted to do a `std::copy` of a map you would need to use a `std::insert_iterator`.

I think that it might be easier to do a `clone` of each shape after the fact, though.

e.g.

```
shape_container shape_container::clone_deep() const
{
    shape_container ret(*this);

    for (std::map<std::string, shape*>::iterator i = ret.data.begin(); i != ret.data.end(); ++i)
    {
        i->second = i->second->clone();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: so for a usual shallow clone function i would simply do `return this;`. I guess this will create a copy on the heap? I want clone_shallow to explicitly copy only the container. deep_copy should also copy the elements the map points to.

Comment: btw, i don't necessarily need to return by value. i just thought it was a good idea and it probably wasn't. but i am willing to learn :)

Comment: I would prefer to go with return by value where I could because it makes the ownership transfer explicit. For your `shape` objects in the map this is a concern as a shallow clone gives you implicit shared ownership where as deep clone must own the new shapes. How are you managing the lifetime of your shapes?

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer/comments! i am not yet managing the lifetime, but i am planning to implement reference counting for my shape class as a next step. otherwise it would be possible to delete elements, that are still referenced by other containers. is that what you're driving at?

Comment: Yes, it was. If you need shared ownership you should consider `shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer. Either `std::tr1::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` if available. This way you won't have to implement reference counting in the objects themselves.

Comment: i think i will be implementing reference counting anyway, to see how it works, because this whole thing is more of a dummy project to teach myself c++ and some basic concepts and patterns. after that, i'll look at shared pointers. thanks for the hint, though!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your example leaks memory because you `new` a `shape_container` in your methods but then it gets copied out through the return value. You should be returning pointers as with your `shape` example.

The compiler errors look to be related in some way to the copying since it's complaining it can't generate an assignment operator for you. Again, try using pointers and that issue should go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you do deep copy of map then you have to a new create map with all element with deep copy.

Think about **reference counting approach** , it will be better approach.

Comment: i will do reference counting later on, but first i want the copying to work :) good point, though. but anyway, i want to have the possibility to deep clone the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to wrap your shape type in a type that performs a deep
copy of the object:

```
class shape_deep_copy_wrapper {
  // ...
public:
  shape_deep_copy_wrapper (shape * shape)
  : m_my_shape (shape)
  {
  }

  shape_deep_copy_wrapper (shape_deep_copy_wrapper const & rhs)
  : m_my_shape (rhs.m_my_shape.deep_copy ())
  {
  }

  // ...

private:
  shape * m_my_shape;
};
```

Then construct a map with this type:

```
typedef std :: map < shape_deep_copy_wrapper , ... > DeepCopy ;
typedef std :: map < shape* , ... >                  ShallowCopy ;
```